# Installing Varnish Cache 4 on Cpanel Server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, varnish, varnish-vcl

I have successfully installed varnish on my VPS and configured it to listen on port 80 with Apache listening on port 8080. When I try accessing any domain name such as www.mydomain.com I get redirected to www.mydomain.com//cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi

Solutions I tried...
Clearing browser cache
Commenting out the redirect in /usr/local/apache/htdocs/index.html (this result in a blank screen.)
removed .htaccess (no luck).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply don't use Varnish + Cpanel. It will never work properly until eventually you will realize you have to get rid of Cpanel.

Cpanel limits you in the way you can configure and maintain your server.

Get rid of it, really. Start from bare bones Linux OS installation and install Varnish + Nginx which is already a much better stack than what Cpanel provides.

Comment: I agree with you, I have tried the Magento 2.3 with Varnish in a Cpanel environment. To make it verse, it is a multisite environment as well. 

My final conclusion also same as yours. Since you commented in 2016, just curious to know whethe you have found any solution to manage the varnish in a cpanel environment by now?

Comment: @MudithaE I mostly never had a need to use cPanel for Magento and Varnish. I've been provisioning servers for many Magento powered shops. An unmanaged VPS with root access and *without cPanel* is so cheap these days, whereas a cPanel managed server is going to be always eating on hidden license cost bundled within monthly fees. If a shop owner is serious about running their website like a clock -they can definitely afford hiring an engineer (like you or myself) to setup the proper server stack which includes NGINX and Varnish. It's going to actually save them money in the long run.